# Bash: extract pattern from middle of a string variable?

Tags: bash, built-in

I'm working on writing a custom Bash completion function for command `foo`.

You can call `foo --help` and get output like:

```
Usage: foo (start | stop | up | down) [options] [ARGS]
```

As a first step, I'd like my completion function to parse this usage message and grab the elements between `(` and `)`. I'd like to use shell builtins as much as possible, spawning external processes like `sed` only when absolutely necessary. Right now I've got:

```
_foo() {
  local cmd=$1 word=$2 usage=$(foo --help) subcmds

  [[ "$usage" =~ .*\((.*)\).* ]] && subcmds="${BASH_REMATCH[1]// |}"

  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$subcmds" -- "$word") )
}

complete -F _foo foo
```

This works, but I wonder if there's a way I could achieve the same results without resorting to `=~` and `BASH_REMATCH`, and instead just combining parameter string manipulations?

I can remove the part of the usage message up to the open paren,

```
"${usage#*\(}"  # start | stop | up | down) [options] [ARGS]
```

and I can remove the part starting at the closing paren,

```
"${usage%)*}"   # Usage: foo (start | stop | up | down
```

but I can't figure out a way to extract just the middle without introducing a temporary variable...

```
tmp="${usage#*\(}"
"${tmp%)*}"
```

I was hoping something like this would work, but no luck

```
"${${usage#*\(}%)*}"
```

Comment: Just introduce the temporary. It is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `extglob` in BASH replacement to get both replacements in a single step:

```
tmp='Usage: foo (start | stop | up | down) [options] [ARGS]'
echo "${tmp//@(*\(|\)*)}"
```

`@(*\(|\)*)` will match either glob `*(` or `)*` and replace it by an empty string.

**Output:**

```
start | stop | up | down
```

---

If you want to strip pipes as well then use:

```
echo "${tmp//@(*\(|\| |\)*)}"
start stop up down
```

(Thanks to OP)

Comment: I like these special extglob cases of pathname expansion. Cool thing here is either `@`, `*` or `+` will give the desired output.

Comment: Nice, that's really clever! Turning on `extglob` seems to be [common practice](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/0845c2183c91054013055ca1966ec1e547fa5b13/bash_completion#L45) when dealing with custom bash completion, which is good to know.

Comment: I need to strip out the pipes `|` too. It's not easy to read, but I ended up with:
`"${tmp//@(*\(|\| |\)*)}"`